# How to create left/ right arrow button as cursor on carousel?

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel and replace the standard cursor with left/ right arrow buttons on hover but cannot find any kind of reference on how to achieve this

```
$(function(){
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
autoplay: 2000,
items:1,
loop: true,
onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Version 1.3

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
      items:1,
      loop:true,
      autoplay:true,
      autoplayTimeout:1000,
      autoplayHoverPause:true,
      navigation : true,
      navigationText : ['<span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>','<span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>'],
  });
});
```

Here is your demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdBBLe

Comment: create a jsfiddle with your code and share to understand the issue.